# Problematic combination of variance in Scala

Tags: scala

Here is an example from the [Scala course on Coursera:](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-005/lecture/83), lecture 4.4

```
class Array[+T] {
  def update(x: T) = ???
}
```

This causes an error in the repl:

```
error: covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type T of value x
```

And on the slides, Martin says that this is a "problematic combination". Why so?

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the "Variance and arrays" section of http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html (from *Programming in Scala* by Odersky, Venners, and Spoon).

Comment: Instead of giving only a link, it would make this a good answer if you include the relevant section